# Java 8 stream to collect a Map of List of items

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a List of Maps which stores the roles and the names of people. For ex:

```
List<Map<String, String>> listOfData

1) Role:  Batsman
   Name:  Player1

2)Role:  Batsman
   Name:  Player2

3)Role:  Bowler
   Name:  Player3
```

Role and Name are the Keys of the map.
I want to convert this into a `Map<String, List<String>> result`, which will give me a list of names for each role, i.e

```
k1: Batsman  v1: [Player1, Player2]
k2: Bowler   v2: [Player3]


listOfData
    .stream()
    .map(entry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entry.get("Role"), entry.get("Name"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Doing this way will not give me a list of names for the role, it will give me a single name. How do i keep collecting the elements of the list and then add it to a key ?

Java code to create base structure:

```
Map<String, String> x1 = ImmutableMap.of("Role", "Batsman", "Name", "Player1");

        Map<String, String> y1 = ImmutableMap.of("Role", "Batsman", "Name", "Player2");

        Map<String, String> z1 = ImmutableMap.of("Role", "Bowler", "Name", "Player3");


        List<Map<String, String>> list = ImmutableList.of(x1, y1, z1);
        Map<String, List<String>> z = list.stream()
                    .flatMap(e -> e.entrySet().stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Based on the idea given by Aomine:

```
list.stream()
    .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.get("Role"), e.get("Name")))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 36):

```
listOfData.stream()
          .flatMap(e -> e.entrySet().stream())
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                         Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, 
                                    Collectors.toList())));
```

**update:**

Slightly different variant to [`user1692342`'s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887953/java-8-stream-to-collect-a-map-of-list-of-items/49889657#49889657) answer for completeness.

```
list.stream()
    .map(e -> Arrays.asList(e.get("Role"), e.get("Name")))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.get(0),
             Collectors.mapping(e -> e.get(1), Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Wouldn't this group by Role and Name? i.e
K1: Role V1: Batsman, Bowler 
K2: Name V2: player1, player2, player3

Comment: This doesn't work for the input. Updated question with sample Java code.

Comment: @user1692342 at the time of writing this answer I actually thought your map was like `Map<String, String> x1 = Map.of( "Batsman",  "Player1"); Map<String, String> y1 = Map.of( "Batsman",  "Player2");` and so forth, looks like you've found the missing operation before i came back :) +1.

Comment: Yeah the main trick was using Collectors.tomapping within the collect. I wasn't aware of that part. Thanks for that!

Comment: @user1692342 you're welcome and update my answer for completeness.

Answer (score 15):

The [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) class provides convenience methods in the form of i.e. [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) which allow to group similar objects by a certain classifier. The classifier method is the input to that particular grouping function. This function will generate a Map with the respective classifier methods value as key and a list of objects that share the same classifier method value as value.

Therefore a code like

```java
Map<String, List<Person>> roles2Persons = 
    lis.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getRole));
```

will generate a mapping for the respective roles `Person` objects may fulfill to a list of `Person` objects that share the same role as the key in the map.

After the above collector was applied the resulting map will contain the desired form of

```
key1: Batsman, values: List(Player1, Player2)
key2: Bowler, values: List(Player3)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic approach to this problem. The `groupBy` method below takes 2 to 3 arguments.

1. A `collection` of type `List<E>`
2. A `keyFn` (key) of type `Function<E, K>`
3. (Optional) A `valueFn` (value) of type `Function<E, V>` or simply `E`

I included some unit tests below.

### CollectionUtils.java

```java
package org.example.util;

import static java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class CollectionUtils {
  public static <E, K, V> Map<K, List<V>> groupBy(
      Collection<E> collection, Function<E, K> keyFn, Function<E, V> valueFn) {
    return collection.stream()
        .map(item -> new SimpleEntry<K, V>(keyFn.apply(item), valueFn.apply(item)))
        .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, mapping(Entry::getValue, toList())));
  }

  public static <E, K> Map<K, List<E>> groupBy(Collection<E> collection, Function<E, K> keyFn) {
    return groupBy(collection, keyFn, Function.identity());
  }

  public static <K, V> Map<K, V> immutableMapOf(K k1, V v1, K k2, V v2) {
    Map<K, V> mutableMap = new HashMap<>();
    mutableMap.put(k1, v1);
    mutableMap.put(k2, v2);
    return unmodifiableMap(mutableMap);
  }
}
```

### CollectionUtilsTest.java

```java
package org.example.util;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static org.example.util.CollectionUtils.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.*;

public class CollectionUtilsTest {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CollectionUtilsTest.class);

  private static final List<Map<String, String>> data =
      asList(
          immutableMapOf("Username", "Batman", "Role", "Leader"),
          immutableMapOf("Username", "Robin", "Role", "Subordinate"),
          immutableMapOf("Username", "Superman", "Role", "Leader"));

  @Test
  public void testGroupBy() {
    logger.info("Test groupBy(Collection<E>, Function<E, K>, Function<E, V>)");
    Map<String, List<String>> grouped = groupBy(data, m -> m.get("Role"), m -> m.get("Username"));

    logger.info("Checking keys...");
    assertNotNull(grouped.get("Leader"));
    assertNotNull(grouped.get("Subordinate"));

    logger.info("Checking values...");
    assertEquals("Batman", grouped.get("Leader").get(0));
    assertEquals("Superman", grouped.get("Leader").get(1));
    assertEquals("Robin", grouped.get("Subordinate").get(0));
  }

  @Test
  public void testGroupBySimple() {
    logger.info("Test groupBy(Collection<E>, Function<E, K>)");
    Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> grouped = groupBy(data, m -> m.get("Role"));

    logger.info("Checking keys...");
    assertNotNull(grouped.get("Leader"));
    assertNotNull(grouped.get("Subordinate"));

    logger.info("Checking values...");
    assertEquals("Batman", grouped.get("Leader").get(0).get("Username"));
    assertEquals("Superman", grouped.get("Leader").get(1).get("Username"));
    assertEquals("Robin", grouped.get("Subordinate").get(0).get("Username"));
  }
}
```