# Create a nested map from Json using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the below Json that I'm reading into nested POJOs with the same structure.

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "age": "30",
      "proData": [
        {
          "year": "1",
          "idList": [
            "234342",
            "532542",
            "325424",
            "234234"
          ]
        },
        {
          "year": "2",
          "idList": [
            "234342",
            "532542",
            "325424",
            "234234"
          ]
        },
        {
          "year": "3",
          "idList": [
            "234342",
            "532542",
            "325424",
            "234234"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Scott",
      "age": "32",
      "proData": [
        {
          "year": "1",
          "idList": [
            "234342",
            "532542",
            "325424",
            "234234"
          ]
        },
        {
          "year": "2",
          "idList": [
            "234342",
            "532542",
            "325424",
            "234234"
          ]
        },
        {
          "year": "3",
          "idList": [
            "234342",
            "532542",
            "325424",
            "234234"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I wanted to map this to a structure like below, the `ProData` can be initialized using each of the string in the `idList`.

`Map<String,Map<String,List<ProData>>> finalMap`

I have written something like the below and it works.

```
        Map<String,Map<String,List<ProData>>> finalMap = new HashMap<>();

        for(Employee employee:root.getEmployees()){
            Map<String,List<ProData>> proDataMap = new HashMap<>();
            for(ProData proData: employee.getProData()){
                List<ProData> finalObjs = new ArrayList<>();
                for(String id:proData.getIdList()){
                   finalObjs.add(new ProData(id));
                }

                proDataMap.put(proData.getYear(),finalObjs);
            }
            finalMap.put(employee.getName(),proDataMap);
        }
```

I wanted to make a better version using the stream API.

Comment: this link has done something like your need, give it a visit :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887953/java-8-stream-to-collect-a-map-of-list-of-items

Comment: [and again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65881359/extract-list-from-inner-pojo-data?noredirect=1#comment116509814_65881359), stop treating StackOverflow as your coder conversion application! Share what you have tried, attempt something with streams to fail, and then ak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end result is a map, so use the `toMap` collector. The maps' keys are the employee names (assuming no duplicates), and the map values require a little bit more work.

```
root.getEmployees().stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(
        Employee::getName,
        Employee::getProDataMap
    )
}
```

Now let's try writing `getProDataMap` in `Employee`. Again we use the `toMap` collector. The keys are the years (assuming no duplicates), and the values are the id lists mapped to `ProData` using the constructor.

```
public Map<String, List<ProData>> getProDataMap() {
    return this.getProData().stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            ProData::getYear,
            proData -> proData.getIdList().stream()
                .map(ProData::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Its what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

should be something similar to,

```
root.stream().forEach(employee -> {
                Map<String,List<ProData>> proDataMap = new HashMap<>();
                employee.getProdData().stream().forEach(data -> {
                    List<ProData> finalObjs = new ArrayList<>();
                    data.getIdList().stream().forEach(data -> {
                        finalObjs.add(new ProData(id));
                    });
                });
            });
```

but regardless you can also use Gson to parse it
https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-parse-json-with-gson/

Comment: What is the advantage of using `collection.stream().forEach(..)` over `collection.forEach(..)`? This is not the way Stream API should be used.